# Jobs/companies header section is bugged in mobile view

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-talent

[image]

Open any company page from https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies and just scroll a little bit. It will loop in resize.

Comment: Also repro'd on Chrome for Android v107.

Comment: Wait, haven’t Jobs been shut down?

Comment: I was wrong, I removed my answer. As animuson pointed out to me: *The Companies section is not being removed and intentionally still exists. They are part of our [brand awareness](https://stackoverflow.co/talent/solutions) offerings.*